# Add image to Scalatest HtmlReporter

Tags: scala, selenium, webdriver, scalatest

I'm writing some selenium tests with Scalatest and capturing some screenshots.  I would like these screenshots to appear in the scalatest html report but the best I can do is use an informer to add an escaped string.  This escaping means I cannot put an  tag in the report.  Will I have to re-write the HtmlReporter class for my purposes or is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use 'markup' instead of 'info', 'markup' will not be escaped and can be use for tag.  The following show an example of showing the capture picture in the HtmlReporter:-

```
go to ("http://www.artima.com")
setCaptureDir("html")  // set the capture directory
capture to ("MyScreenShot.png")
markup("<img src='MyScreenShot.png' />")
```

Comment: Excelent thanks.  Just want to point out that this method is part of FlatSpec (and probably other 'Specs') so if you want to use it in a class outside of your test class you need to pass an implicit markup: Documenter.  For example I am using the page object model and want to report from the page object.

Comment: To add to this once again, the method markup is not on a common interface of FlatSpec, FunSpec, FeatureSpec etc so unfortunately I couldn't put eveything I wanted in a general trait and have to have a trait specifically for my FlatSpec tests.  If someone wants to write FeatureSpec tests they will have to duplicate the trait which is obviously not good.  I will find out how I can request it as a new feature on ScalaTest as I think it makes sense...

Comment: See http://code.google.com/p/scalatest/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=33